# append string to file using sed command

Tags: sed, zsh

I want to be able to add a plugin to ZSH with one-liner into .zshrc file.
Found this discussion but it adds the string to the beginning of the list while I need it to add it in the end of the list:
[Search and replace a specific line with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188171/search-and-replace-a-specific-line-with-bash)

for example:

```
plugins=(
  aaa
  bbb
)
```

should be changed to:

```
plugins=(
  aaa
  bbb
  ccc
)
```

I couldnt modify the command to achieve it..

Thanks

```
sed 's/\(^plugins=([^)]*\)/\1 zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting/' testfile
```

Comment: Please do note that your `plugins` line has multiple lines, and in the referred example it only has 1 line.  rewriting that line to a single-line might be the easiest option.

Comment: Is it possible to catch both use cases? Basically I need to catch everything until the ')'

Comment: The closes solution I know is: `cat testfile | tr '\n' '#' | sed 's/\(^plugins=([^)]*\)/\1 zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting/' | tr '#' '\n'`  

Comment: Ok, final attempt ():   `sed $(awk '/plugins/,/\)/{ n=NR }END{ print n}' testfile)'s/\([^}]*\))/\1 zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting)/' testfile`  (AWK returns the line number to be _changed_)

Comment: thanks! 
both works but seems to be very complicated for such a simple task isnt it?
is there maybe a simpler way?

Comment: It also does not capture both the multi-line and single-line cases

Comment: Why don't you use a [text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_editor)?

Comment: @DvirLevy: I have a typo in this _final_ attempt, when correcting it it should work   (Please change `}` to `)`).

Comment: @Luuk thanks for your help but it still not working for both cases :(

Comment: "still not working" is a very bad description.  I think it is working (seeing this: https://onlinegdb.com/mbgPr9Fl3 )  Please [edit] the question to make **CLEAR** what your problem is, (or ask a NEW question).